# Linked List Exercise Mark Scheme Error

Tags: linked-list

I'm looking through some specimen papers for a famous exam board as I'm teaching the syllabus next year.

I came across this question:

> (a) A linked list is to be set up that stores names in alphabetical order. Show the final state of
>   this linked list after the following operations are carried out.
>
> ```
> CreateLinkedList
> AddItem(“Nushie”)
> AddItem(“Kellie”)
> AddItem(“Scarlett”)
> RemoveItem(“Nushie”)
> AddItem(“Jon”)
> ```

Now as far as I can tell, and I have checked this with pen and paper, as well as with a Python Linked List implementation, the result should be:

`Head -> John -> Scarlett -> Kellie -> None`

However, the mark-scheme gives:

`Start -> Jon -> Kellie -> Scarlett -> 0`

Differences in nomenclature aside, (start, 0 instead of head, None), one of these answers is presumably wrong, even if we allow the adding to happen at the tail instead of the head.

Could someone please confirm which answer is correct?

Am I perhaps missing something?

Comment: *stores names **in alphabetical order***

Comment: Ah, a good reminder that the mantra of "read the question" applies to me too... Thanks.